# Repair Database using .FRM .IBD .OPT Files ( Hard copy mysql folder )

Tags: mysql, backup, query, table

I had a crash on my server.
The only thing I could do was hard copy the `mysql` folder
Now I am trying to access my database again through the PHPMyAdmin interface.
Some databases (mostly WordPress) run and run well
But some databases are only viewed and their content is not displayed

For example
[image: table doesn't exist]

I used `REPAIR TABLE` query but it doesn't help

[image]

Comment: first check the mysql error log and see whazt it shows and also gives advice what to do, and then you can try to make a recpovery for the next time backup backzu backup

Comment: in \data\mysql i have mysql.log but it's empty

Comment: then try the recovery instructions on the mysql website., but basically t looks bad without bin log, see if your backups have bnot also the mysql folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY
Thanx Dexter!

Answer link after about 6hours searching the internet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56641702/12873930

###Files require to restore

`xampp(old folder)/mysql/data/`

```
ibdata1
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
<databasename>/*.frm
<databasename>/*.ibd
```

###Step 1

1. After installed the same version of xampp.
2. **Do not start the apache or myql**

###Step 2

- Go to the `mysql/data` folder and **replace** the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0`, and `ib_logfile1`
- Now copy paste your `database` folder from your old xampp backup to the newly installed xampp folder `c:/xampp/mysql/data/` that contain `.frm` and `.ibd` files, If you are not sure try with one database.

###Step 3

- Go to `c:/xampp/mysql/bin` and look for `my.cn`.
- Open the `my.cn` file and look for `#skip-innodb` and under that look for the line that says `innodb_log_file_size=5M` change it to `170M`. `innodb_log_file_size=170M`. This is your log file size and if you are not sure just set it to `170`

###Step 4

- Now open the file `mysql_start.bat` (Windows Batch file) that is in the `c:/xampp/` directory.
- Add `–innodb_force_recovery=6` after the `... --console`

  ```
   ....

   mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
   –innodb_force_recovery=6
   if errorlevel 1 goto error
   goto finish
  ```

###Step 5

- Now Start your Apache and Mysql.
- Go to your `phpmyadmin` and check for your database and its tables. if you do not get any errors you are on the right track.
- **Stop the Apache and Mysql** and copy paste the rest of the databases.